# How do I make rounded button-group in Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

There used to be a "round" class on Foundation 5 that transforms a button-group to have rounded edges. How do I do this in Foundation 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in Foundation 6. The rules have been completely removed along with others to reduce the file size. Your best bet is to copy the rules into the Foundation 6 css file or into a custom css file (it's up to you).

Here are the css rules you'll need (taken directly from the latest Foundation 5 file, with no alterations):

```
.button-group {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0; }
  .button-group:before, .button-group:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .button-group:after {
    clear: both; }
  .button-group.even-2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 50%; }
    .button-group.even-2 li > button, .button-group.even-2 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-2 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-2 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-2 li button, .button-group.even-2 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group.even-3 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    .button-group.even-3 li > button, .button-group.even-3 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-3 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-3 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-3 li button, .button-group.even-3 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group.even-4 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 25%; }
    .button-group.even-4 li > button, .button-group.even-4 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-4 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-4 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-4 li button, .button-group.even-4 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group.even-5 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 20%; }
    .button-group.even-5 li > button, .button-group.even-5 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-5 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-5 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-5 li button, .button-group.even-5 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group.even-6 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 16.66667%; }
    .button-group.even-6 li > button, .button-group.even-6 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-6 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-6 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-6 li button, .button-group.even-6 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group.even-7 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 14.28571%; }
    .button-group.even-7 li > button, .button-group.even-7 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-7 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-7 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-7 li button, .button-group.even-7 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group.even-8 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    width: 12.5%; }
    .button-group.even-8 li > button, .button-group.even-8 li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.even-8 li:first-child button, .button-group.even-8 li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.even-8 li button, .button-group.even-8 li .button {
      width: 100%; }
  .button-group > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px; }
    .button-group > li > button, .button-group > li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group > li:first-child button, .button-group > li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
  .button-group.stack > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    float: none; }
    .button-group.stack > li > button, .button-group.stack > li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.stack > li:first-child button, .button-group.stack > li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.stack > li > button, .button-group.stack > li .button {
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      border-left-width: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid;
      display: block;
      margin: 0; }
    .button-group.stack > li > button {
      width: 100%; }
    .button-group.stack > li:first-child button, .button-group.stack > li:first-child .button {
      border-top: 0; }
  .button-group.stack-for-small > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px; }
    .button-group.stack-for-small > li > button, .button-group.stack-for-small > li .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.stack-for-small > li:first-child button, .button-group.stack-for-small > li:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
      .button-group.stack-for-small > li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%; }
        .button-group.stack-for-small > li > button, .button-group.stack-for-small > li .button {
          border-left: 1px solid;
          border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
        .button-group.stack-for-small > li:first-child button, .button-group.stack-for-small > li:first-child .button {
          border-left: 0; }
        .button-group.stack-for-small > li > button, .button-group.stack-for-small > li .button {
          border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
          border-left-width: 0;
          border-top: 1px solid;
          display: block;
          margin: 0; }
        .button-group.stack-for-small > li > button {
          width: 100%; }
        .button-group.stack-for-small > li:first-child button, .button-group.stack-for-small > li:first-child .button {
          border-top: 0; } }
  .button-group.radius > * {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px; }
    .button-group.radius > * > button, .button-group.radius > * .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.radius > *:first-child button, .button-group.radius > *:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.radius > *,
    .button-group.radius > * > a,
    .button-group.radius > * > button,
    .button-group.radius > * > .button {
      border-radius: 0; }
    .button-group.radius > *:first-child, .button-group.radius > *:first-child > a, .button-group.radius > *:first-child > button, .button-group.radius > *:first-child > .button {
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px; }
    .button-group.radius > *:last-child, .button-group.radius > *:last-child > a, .button-group.radius > *:last-child > button, .button-group.radius > *:last-child > .button {
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px; }
  .button-group.radius.stack > * {
    display: block;
    margin: 0; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > * > button, .button-group.radius.stack > * .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child button, .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > * > button, .button-group.radius.stack > * .button {
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      border-left-width: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid;
      display: block;
      margin: 0; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > * > button {
      width: 100%; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child button, .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child .button {
      border-top: 0; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > *,
    .button-group.radius.stack > * > a,
    .button-group.radius.stack > * > button,
    .button-group.radius.stack > * > .button {
      border-radius: 0; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child, .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child > a, .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child > button, .button-group.radius.stack > *:first-child > .button {
      -webkit-top-left-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px; }
    .button-group.radius.stack > *:last-child, .button-group.radius.stack > *:last-child > a, .button-group.radius.stack > *:last-child > button, .button-group.radius.stack > *:last-child > .button {
      -webkit-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.0625em) {
    .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 -2px; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * .button {
        border-left: 1px solid;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child .button {
        border-left: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *,
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > a,
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > button,
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > .button {
        border-radius: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child > a, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child > .button {
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child > a, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child > .button {
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * {
      display: block;
      margin: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * .button {
        border-left: 1px solid;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child .button {
        border-left: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * .button {
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid;
        display: block;
        margin: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > button {
        width: 100%; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child .button {
        border-top: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *,
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > a,
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > button,
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > * > .button {
        border-radius: 0; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child > a, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:first-child > .button {
        -webkit-top-left-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px; }
      .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child > a, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child > button, .button-group.radius.stack-for-small > *:last-child > .button {
        -webkit-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; } }
  .button-group.round > * {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px; }
    .button-group.round > * > button, .button-group.round > * .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.round > *:first-child button, .button-group.round > *:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.round > *,
    .button-group.round > * > a,
    .button-group.round > * > button,
    .button-group.round > * > .button {
      border-radius: 0; }
    .button-group.round > *:first-child, .button-group.round > *:first-child > a, .button-group.round > *:first-child > button, .button-group.round > *:first-child > .button {
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1000px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px;
      border-top-left-radius: 1000px; }
    .button-group.round > *:last-child, .button-group.round > *:last-child > a, .button-group.round > *:last-child > button, .button-group.round > *:last-child > .button {
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1000px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px;
      border-top-right-radius: 1000px; }
  .button-group.round.stack > * {
    display: block;
    margin: 0; }
    .button-group.round.stack > * > button, .button-group.round.stack > * .button {
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
    .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child button, .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child .button {
      border-left: 0; }
    .button-group.round.stack > * > button, .button-group.round.stack > * .button {
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      border-left-width: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid;
      display: block;
      margin: 0; }
    .button-group.round.stack > * > button {
      width: 100%; }
    .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child button, .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child .button {
      border-top: 0; }
    .button-group.round.stack > *,
    .button-group.round.stack > * > a,
    .button-group.round.stack > * > button,
    .button-group.round.stack > * > .button {
      border-radius: 0; }
    .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child, .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child > a, .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child > button, .button-group.round.stack > *:first-child > .button {
      -webkit-top-left-radius: 1rem;
      -webkit-top-right-radius: 1rem;
      border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
      border-top-right-radius: 1rem; }
    .button-group.round.stack > *:last-child, .button-group.round.stack > *:last-child > a, .button-group.round.stack > *:last-child > button, .button-group.round.stack > *:last-child > .button {
      -webkit-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
      -webkit-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.0625em) {
    .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 -2px; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * .button {
        border-left: 1px solid;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child .button {
        border-left: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *,
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > a,
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > button,
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > .button {
        border-radius: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child > a, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child > .button {
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1000px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px;
        border-top-left-radius: 1000px; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child > a, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child > .button {
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1000px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px;
        border-top-right-radius: 1000px; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * {
      display: block;
      margin: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * .button {
        border-left: 1px solid;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child .button {
        border-left: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * .button {
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid;
        display: block;
        margin: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > button {
        width: 100%; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child .button {
        border-top: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *,
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > a,
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > button,
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > * > .button {
        border-radius: 0; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child > a, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:first-child > .button {
        -webkit-top-left-radius: 1rem;
        -webkit-top-right-radius: 1rem;
        border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 1rem; }
      .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child > a, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child > button, .button-group.round.stack-for-small > *:last-child > .button {
        -webkit-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
        -webkit-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem; } }

.button-bar:before, .button-bar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }
.button-bar:after {
  clear: both; }
.button-bar .button-group {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.625rem; }
  .button-bar .button-group div {
    overflow: hidden; }
```

[**Foundation 6 Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/duy2kr1w/)

Comment: It sucks that they removed the native support for it. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: You're welcome. A lot of the Foundation 5 functionality has been trimmed, which is why I've not switched to Foundation 6.

Answer (score 0):

Rounded button-group is essentially rounding of of the first and last buttons on the left and on the right, respectively.

HTML:

```
<div class="button-group">
  <a class="button first">First</a>
  <a class="button">Middle</a>
  <a class="button last">Last</a>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
@mixin radius-left($radius) {
    border-radius-topleft:              $radius;
    border-radius-bottomleft:           $radius;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         $radius;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      $radius;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     $radius;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  $radius;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius:      $radius;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius:   $radius;
}
@mixin radius-right($radius) {
    border-radius-topright:             $radius;
    border-radius-bottomright:          $radius;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:        $radius;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     $radius;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    $radius;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius:     $radius;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius:  $radius;
}
..
..
.button.first { @include radius-left(10px); }
.button.last  { @include radius-right(10px); }
```

Just a few easy to understand lines providing complete control over the rounding.